# Loading bar using Splash Screen in Kotlin without XML

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

So I was thinking of adding a loading/progress bar to my android app to show when its loaded in. However I wasn't able to find a source on how to create this without the use of a xml file as the splash screen.
Currently I use the `Theme.SplashScreen` inside the styles.xml file. Like so:

```
<style name="LoadingScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_image</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/papaya_orange</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/papaya_orange</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/LightMode</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">#444444</item> 
</style>
```

And then to load it in the onCreate:

```
installSplashScreen()
```

Anyone know how to implement this? Thanks